# Как перейти на контроллер?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Нужно перейти на 1 контроллер с помощью "Кнопка" на DetailYV. Как это сделать?[!

```
-(IBAction)home:(id)sender{

 myNewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier :@"myNewViewController"];
if (![self.presentedViewController isBeingDismissed]){ //проверить не открыты ли другие VC, если открыты - закрыть их
    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
[self presentViewController:myNewVC animated:YES completion:nil ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать программно для "Кнопка".

```
DetailYV * myNewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier :@"myNewViewController"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myNewVC];

[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self addChildViewController:navigationController];
```

Comment: добавил в код изменения

Comment: Удалите последнюю строку кода, изменил ответ

Comment: Работает. Но при этом создается новый navigationBar.

Comment: сделайте его hidden `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

Comment: попробуйте в методе viewWillAppear

Comment: `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:YES];
  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Можно при открытии модального контроллера "DetailYV" передать в него как проперти сам контроллер с которого вы открываете его. А по нажатии на "кнопку" в "DetailYV" делать следующее:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.mainVC.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

где "mainVC" это контроллер который вы передали при создании "DetailYV"